# Load all dropdown inside kendo Ui grid

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-grid

I am  using kendo UI grid with editable dropdown in cell .This dropdown on the grid loads data only after clicking on it ,but i need to load on pageload. however, I managed to load data in multiple dropdowns but it loads only on double click now.

Following is the code for loading all dropdown in grid

```
 {
                    field: 'Installer',
                    title: 'Installer Name',
                    width: 250,

                   editor: $scope.categoryDropDownEditor,
                     template: '<span class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header" style="width: 220px;"><span class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default k-state-hover"><span class="k-input ng-scope">#=Installer.InstallerName#</span><span class="k-select"><span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s">select</span></span></span><input style="width: 220px; display: none;" ></span>'
                }
```

and this is code for loading dropdown through editor

```
$scope.categoryDropDownEditor = function (container, options) {
       var editor = $('<input kendo-drop-down-list   k-data-text-field="\'InstallerName\'" k-data-value-field="\'InstallerID\'"  k-data-source="ddlDataSource"  k-on-change="GetEditPriestSettings(dataItem, kendoEvent)" style="width:250px"   data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
            .appendTo(container);
    }
```

Is there any better way to load all dropdown and also to make dropdown load on single click.[image: on first click] 
on second click dropdown data loads
[image: on second click]

Comment: On the dropdown widget try using the property `autoBind: true`. You can find more information about this property in the widget's official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after lot of research opening kendodropdown manually with timeout worked.

```
setTimeout(function () {
            var x = $('#DropDown_' + id).data("kendoDropDownList").open();

        }, 100)
```